# Why does my launchd script not run at login?

Tags: launchd, login, startup, screensaver, login-items

I have tried to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13372744/2397253) so that at login, the currently configured screensaver becomes the desktop background. Therefore, I have created the following script:

```
# login.sh
/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine -background &
```

I have then created a launch service as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/my_login_items.plist` with the content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>Label</key>
   <string>com.user.loginscript</string>
   <key>Program</key>
   <string>/path/to/login.sh</string>
   <key>RunAtLoad</key>
   <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And then run `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/my_login_items.plist`.
Nothing happens, however.

Comment: Does `login.sh` work when you run it from the command line? (I'm assuming it does, but wanted to check). When you `launchctl load` does it work? (Again, I'm assuming it doesn't, but need to check). Finally, and this strays into "answer" territory, could you try adding `StandardOutPath` and `StandardErrorPath` to your `plist` so the agent logs whats happening? (`<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/tmp/test.stdout</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/tmp/test.stderr</string>`)

Comment: @JohnN Both of your assumptions are correct. I added the path keys, but both log files stay empty.

Comment: Ah, that's disappointing. I'll have a play around and see if I can replicate this.

Answer (score 3):

This is a deeply unsatisfying answer, but I got it to work by running `/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine -background &` in a subshell. I changed `login.sh` to...

```
#!/bin/bash
longname=$0
shortname=$(basename "${longname}")
echo "$(date -u "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") ${shortname} (${longname}) running..."
output=$(/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine -background)    # <- COMMAND GOES HERE            
echo "$(date -u "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") ${shortname} ended."
```

...and that works (my usual static desktop changes to my default screensaver). I use this idiom for other launchd tasks, running the tasks in a subshell so I can easily test whether the operation succeeded and log `$output`. I don't understand why this works while your original doesn't, but at least it does work.

Note that I removed the `&` from the end of your command - I'm not convinced this is necessary with `launchd`, and it was preventing my wrapper script from logging that it had ended (though the `&` wasn't the cause of the original problem).